# How export password of customers from Magento2 to other cms?

Tags: magento2, export

I want migrate a Magento2 to Woocommerce, but I see that these 2 cms uses a different login system.

If I would create a plugin/hook on wordpress for allow the login with the password that the customers used on Magento, what library I must import on Wordpress from  Magento?

Otherwise, there is a system that convert the password from Magento to a system recognized by Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Magento user passwords are stored using MD5 Cipher and is stored under

```
SELECT email, password_hash FROM customer_entity;
```

Unless Wordpress also uses MD5 cipher you will need to decifer the passwords hash and cipher it back into the wordpress password cipher.

To the best of my knowledge the isn't a library that would do this out of the box.

Documentation reference on how to get your cipher key:

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/encryption-key.html

Comment: By default, Magento uses sha256

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to login with a Magento password.

I will use this snippet to create a hook for wordpress.

```
 $currentPassword = 'password, extracted from db - table customer_entity';

$magento_pwd_parts = explode(':', $currentPassword);
$hash = $magento_pwd_parts['0'];
$salt = $magento_pwd_parts['1'];

if($hash === hash( 'sha256', $salt.'password sent from browser for login' ))
{
    echo 'logged!';
}
```